# Solr Request taking too much time for ONLY FIRST request. Why?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 3.6.1 ( I know it's old and should be upgraded but can't do that right a way).
I'm facing issue where ONLY FIRST search request takes too much time (~40Sec) where subsequent request will be responded successfully in not more than ~60-70ms.

Could somebody explain me why is this happening ? I checked that It's not user specific, It happens only for per restart of same server.

I tried to following approaches
1. Enabling (marking TRUE) useColdSearcher attribute
2. Creating FirstSearcher with default value without any Facets or filters

But I didn't find any approach working. Is there anyone who faced same problem and overcame this situation with any approach?

Thanks for your help.
Dev.

Comment: If you set useColdSearcher to true, you prevent warmup query. And you have to replace the string "warming query" in my answer with your actual query, so that the cache can be filled with real data.

Answer (score 0):

Solr fills up some caches when executing the first query. This may take some time. You can configure a warm up query to prevent that your user experience that phenomenon.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching for basics.

For example (in your solrconfig.xml):

```
<listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <lst><str name="q">warming query</str><str name="fq">type:ebook</str><str name="start">0</str><str name="rows">10</str><str name="excludeFromLogs">1</str></lst>
  </arr>
</listener>

<listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <lst><str name="q">warming query</str><str name="fq">type:ebook</str><str name="start">0</str><str name="rows">10</str><str name="excludeFromLogs">1</str></lst>
  </arr>
</listener>

<useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
```

Comment: @ Uwe Allner - I tried this approach but it's not working. Somehow static Search request are not made at startup. is there any other way or way to debug why this approach is not working ?

Comment: @DevendraW Do you have any configuration preventing the autowarm queries to execute? Please show your solrconfig.xml.

Comment: It's too long can't send it here. If you can share your email ID then I will mail it to you.

Comment: I must not post my email openly; but perhaps we can get to this problem anyway. Have you had a look at your server log? Has the warmup query really not been executed, or did it just not fill the caches adequately? See that for debugging the parameter "excludeFromLogs" is set to 0!

Comment: Yes, I checked in logs too and there are no logs generated which say Static search request is being made to Solr Server.